# \newcommand with arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I have a few convenience commands defined in my TeX document:

```
\newcommand{\figref}[2][\ref]{Fig.~#1{#2}}  % Figure
\newcommand{\tabref}[2][\ref]{Table~#1{#2}}  % Table
\newcommand{\equref}[2][\eqref]{Eq.~#1{#2}}  % Equation
\newcommand{\algref}[2][\ref]{Algorithm~#1{#2}}  % Algorithm (Pseudocode)
\newcommand{\secref}[2][\ref]{Section~#1{#2}}  % Section
\newcommand{\chapref}[2][\ref]{Chapter~#1{#2}}  % Chapter
```

These commands allow me to easily switch between shortened (Fig.) and unshortened (Figure) references as per requirements, and they even work in cases like:

```
\caption{This is a figure with multiple subfigures. In \figref[\subref]{fig:first_subfigure} we see X, while in \figref[\subref]{fig:second_subfigure} we see Y.}
```

However sometimes in my text I have references like

```
In Figs.~\ref{fig:1}, \ref{fig:2}, and \ref{fig:3} we can see that ...
```

Is there a way I can make these commands handle an arbitrary number of arguments, such that `\figref{fig:1}` would expand to `Fig.~\ref{fig:1}`

[image]

`\figref{fig:1,fig:2}` would expand to `Figs.~\ref{fig:1} and \ref{fig:2}`

[image]

and `\figref{fig:1,fig:2,fig:3,fig:4}` would expand to `Figs.~\ref{fig:1}, \ref{fig:2}, \ref{fig:3}, and \ref{fig:4}`

[image]

with any arbitrary number of arguments then being handled in this same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you familiarize yourself with the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and its *two* main user macros: `\cref` and `\crefrange`. They make in unnecessary to define separate macros to cross-reference figures, tables, sections, equations, chapters, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\newcommand\creflastconjunction{, and } % Oxford comma

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:a}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:bb}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:ccc}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:dddd}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:a}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:b}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:c}

\cref{fig:bb}

\cref{fig:a,fig:bb,fig:dddd,fig:ccc}

\cref{fig:bb,fig:dddd,fig:a}

\crefrange{eq:a}{eq:c}

\cref{eq:b,fig:ccc}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\figref{m}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF{#1}
   {     
     \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}     
     \seq_set_map:NNn\l_tmpa_seq\l_tmpa_seq{\ref{##1}}
     \int_compare:nNnTF {\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}={1} 
       {Fig.\nobreakspace}{Figs.\nobreakspace}
     \seq_use:Nnnn\l_tmpa_seq{~and~}{,~}{~and~}
   }
 }
 
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\figref{a}

\figref{a,b}

\figref{a,b,c,d}

\refstepcounter{figure}\label{a}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{b} 
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{c} 
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{d} 
\end{document}
```

(`\seq_use:Nnnn\l_tmpa_seq{~and~}{,~}{,~and~}` for the last comma)

[image]